# Probability of obtaining all binary strings during a round robin tournament

Tags: probability

Recently in cricket, after three games of a **round robin** tournament, the following situation occurred:

[image]

Observe that all binary strings of length three appear in the form column. Assuming each team is equally likely to win in a particular match, what is the probability of this occurring?

I wrote some code to simulate this (although I wouldn't be surprised if it had  errors) and obtained an approximate probability of 0.152.

More generally, what is the probability of the analogous situation occurring after $2^n$ teams have played $n$ games?

Comment: someone just asked this yesterday.  your post is an almost duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741284/ipl-2018-binary-permutations-from-50-50-matches

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen that. The approximate value of $0.152$ for the $n=3$ case is probably useful information, which I'm more confident about now.